# How Can i know the appropriate partition of ubuntu to be deleted?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, reinstall

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 which is not supported right now (unfortunately, I didn't know that when I was installing it!).

Here is the my partition as shown by Windows:

[image: Disk management]

I have already made my pc boot directly to windows by EasyBCD software, in order to proceed in deleting process.

So, I want to delete this old version and install Ubuntu 18.04, but I don't know which partitions to delete!!!

Can I install version bionic beaver directly over the old version of Ubuntu?
Can I assume it will erase the old files and install the new ones similarly in windows?

Comment: Is there anything on either the Windows or Ubuntu 14 partitions you want to keep? Do you want a dual boot or just a clean Ubuntu 18.04 only PC?

Comment: @Broadsworde i want to keep windows and install ubuntu 18 in the partition where ubuntu 14.10 was installed. !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what we see in your screenshot we can only **guess** which partitions hold your Ubuntu. It definitely is not those that are NTFS formatted, and it is also unlikely the unallocated space. So there is a 134 GB Partition possibly holding Ubuntu, and a 2,9 GB Parition presumably Linux SWAP. Windows will not see those partitions because they are formatted in another file system.

To find out just boot an Ubuntu installer from USB (take any but I recommend you use the latest 18.04) from where you can "try out" Ubuntu to mount and inspect all partitions including Ubuntu and Windows partitions. Start **Gparted** there to see more details on the partition layout.

If you decide to overwrite Ubuntu with the new version then please first

## [Make a backup of all your data including those from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054163/how-can-i-know-the-appropriate-partition-of-ubuntu-to-be-deleted)

Only if that was done you can safely install Ubuntu 18.04 just over the existing Ubuntu 14.04 partition on choosing "something else" in the installation process. Chose `/` as a mount point for root and let it continue to use the existing `/swap` partition.

If the format options was unticked then your previous HOME partition will still be there after the installation finished. In case you chose the same username even many of your personal setting will be preserved.

Tick the format option if you decide to start from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, no way other to make important stuff bold an red otherwise ;)